Одинковые фразы, но противоположные контексты
Не надо МЕНЯ уговаривать // тактовое ударение на МЕНЯ
Меня не надо уговаривать // позиционное ударение на меня

Грамматика во фразах одинаковая, акцент во фразах одинаковый (в первой фразе ударение речевое, во второй позиционное). Смысл фраз тоже одинаковый.
Почему тогда эти фразы всегда употребляются в противоположных контекстах?

Что такое позиционное ударение? Я не пользуюсь этим термином, а  в Сети не нашла нужной информации. Дайте пжста ссылку)

Логическое ударение в предложении выделяется или интонацией или (на письме) порядком слов. Первое я называю интонационным(тактовым) ударением, второе позиционным. Оба они суть логические ударения.

Этот  загадочный русский язык! Никогда иностранцам не понять русскую душу! Но мы и сами понимаем себя на интуитивном уровне)
Вот грамматическое предложение с правильным порядком слов: Не надо уговаривать меня.
Нет! Никуда не годится!  И мы начинаем перемешивать слова:
Меня не надо уговаривать. Меня уговаривать не надо Не надо меня уговаривать. Уговаривать меня не надо. Выбираем подходящий вариант (как выбираем?!): Не надо меня уговаривать.
Но и это еще не всё! Даже из этого одного структурного варианта  мы можем сделать три разных сообщения с помощью логического ударения: Не нАдо меня уговаривать.  Не надо менЯ уговаривать.  Не надо меня уговАривать.
Здесь уже выбор по контексту:
(1) Не нАдо меня /  уговаривать.  Я дано уже согласен.
(2) Не надо менЯ  /  уговаривать.  Уговаривайте остальных.
(3) Не надо меня уговАривать. Попрбуйте убедить чем-нибудь конкретным.
Далее проверка:
Структура (2) нехороша,  так как приходится тактовое ударение менЯ усиливать голосом, лучше так:  МенЯ уговаривать  / не надо.  Уговаривайте остальных.  Если логическое  ударение сместить относительно тактового,  то силовых усилий там не требуется.
Структура (3) не имеет логического выделения нужного слова, поэтому лучше использовать такой вариант: (3) УговАривать меня / не надо.
Вывод.  Предложение имеет три смысловых варианта  для разного контекста в зависимости от логического ударения, при этом структура предложения строится так, чтобы  обеспечить позиционное смещение логического ударения относительного тактового ударения.
Грамматическая справка. Предложение строится из отдельных фраз, которые в свою очередь делятся на синтагмы, или такты.  Обычно тактовое ударение  падает на слово в конце синтагмы. При смещении ударения в другую позицию  тактовое ударение становится логическим и выделяет нужное по смыслу слово.
ИНТЕРЕСНО. Любопытно, что выбор нужной структуры предложения мы делаем практически мгновенно и при этом еще учитываем следующий контекст. Вот такие мы гениальные, если что.

Предложение имеет один смысловой вариант - не надо меня уговаривать. Другое дело, что логическим ударением мы как бы меняем контекст (то есть меняется тема и рема предложения местами), но смысл остается одним и тем же. Напишите про тему и рему и их связь с логическим ударением. Что вообще такое логическое ударение, если оно не меняет ни грамматику ни смысл предложения, что оно меняет, с чем оно связуется?
